# android how to have a fixed layout but it will also adjust itself on different screensize

Tags: android

I am developing some calculation app. This app will display the results on a table. For now i use "wrap_content" on height and width plus weight of my layout which will make it adjusting the border itself. However this make the table looks poorly designed . The example::

What i want it look like: the value inside it will not change the borders.

```
 ____________________________________________________
|                      Prepaid                       |
|____________________________________________________|
|  Years  |     First Payment     | Permonth Payment |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|  Year1  |     1231234345345     |     123123123    |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|  Year2  |    78978978978999     |    12312312312   |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|  Year3  |     5675675675677     |     6789679677   |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|  Year4  |     6786786786786     |     456456456    |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|  Year5  |     45645645645666    |       345345     |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
```

But what's happening :

```
 ____________________________________________________
|                      Prepaid                       |
|____________________________________________________|
|  Years  |     First Payment     | Permonth Payment |
|_________|_______________________|__________________|
|Year1|   1231234345345    |        123123123        |
|____ |____________________|_________________________|
|Year2|      78978978978999       |       2312312    |
|_____|___________________________|__________________|
|Year3|     5675675675677     |     6789679677       |
|_____|_______________________|______________________|
|Year4|     6786786786786     |     456456456        |
|_____|_______________________|______________________|
|Year5|      45645645645666     |       345345       |
|_____|_________________________|____________________|
```

my xml code for tables:

```
  <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idAADM"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/AADM"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idtenor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="11"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/tenor"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/tppm"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="69"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/angm"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id1thn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/thn1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbalaa1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbal1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id2thn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/thn2"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbalaa2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbal2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id3thn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/thn3"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbalaa3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbal3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id4thn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/thn4"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbalaa4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbal4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id5thn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/thn5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbalaa5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tumbal5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
```

my custom drawable cell_shape and cell_shape1 (same code both)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
 <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

How to have a fixed table that will not change whenever the value gets longer or shorter. And this layout will also not change the size if the screen is different(not changing in different screensize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that you are giving width property as wrap content for the views with which you are adding weight property.
Change the android:layout_width = "0dp" for the view for which you have given weight.
I guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: what about the linear layout? with the weightsum, should it be changed to 0dp aswell?

Comment: {<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >}

Comment: No , with the weightsum property its better to have width as match parent or width should be some fixed value. Weight actually decides what portion of parent view should , the child view should get